# Rails Testing Devise registrations_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I only want a person with a specific email to be able to register. I am using Devise and here is my internal controllers/admins/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if params[:admin][:email] == Rails.application.credentials.development[:admin_email]
      super
    end
 end
```

I'm trying to send an email, password, and confirmation password inside my test.

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Admins::RegistrationsController do
  it 'does not allow xxx@gmail.com with very-secret password to register' do 
    @request.env["devise.mapping"]=Devise.mappings[:admin]
    patch :create, admin: {email: 'xxx@gmail.com", password: "very-secret", password-confirmations: "very-secret"}
  end
end
```

I get an Argument Error: unknown keyword: admin. How do I write a proper patch request for Devise?

EDIT:
My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, controllers: {sessions: 'admins/sessions', 
  registrations: 'admins/registrations'}
  ....
```

My rake routes

```
admin_registration PATCH  /admins(.:format) 
    admins/registrations#update
                   PUT    /admins(.:format)                                                                        
    admins/registrations#update
                   DELETE /admins(.:format)                                                                        
    admins/registrations#destroy
                   POST   /admins(.:format)                                                                        
    admins/registrations#create
```

MORE INFO:
This is print out from using the browser, it does work in the browser:

```
  Started POST "/admins" for ::1 at 2019-7-03 21:08:58 -0500
  Processing by Admins::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"_", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "admin"=>{"email"=>"abc@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  inside registrations_controller.rb CREATE
```

Comment: Since you are testing the creation, you need `put` not `patch`. Also ,Can you try `put '/admin/{your-devise-model-name-plural}', admin: .....`

Comment: sorry -deleted my last comment, running in wrong folder.

Comment: Thanks for writing @Mosaaleb! I typed in put '/admin/admins', admin: {email: "abc@gmail.com", password: "secret", password_confirmation: "secret"} and I have an Argument Error unknown keyword: admin.

Comment: Can you add your routes file?

Comment: thanks @Mosaaleb. Added my routes info.

Comment: Where this `Admins::RegistrationsController` come from. It seems from your routes that you don't have any namespaces called `admin`. See my answer

Comment: Is it because of `patch :create, admin: {email: 'xxx@gmail.com", password: "very-secret", password-confirmations: "very-secret"}` ? `admin` here is just the key of sending params

Comment: Hi @quyetdc sorry, I'm not very familiar with rails, or http requests. What do you mean 'admin is just the key of sending params'

Comment: @Mosaaleb the routes are made from Devise. And it works properly in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post :create, params: {"admin"=>{"email"=>"abc@gmail.com", "password"=>"very-secret", "password_confirmation"=>"very-secret"}}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

`post '/admins', params: admin_attributes`

You can define the `admin_attributes` using `let` if you want to reuse it again inside another examples.

```
Rspec.describe RegistrationsController do
let(:admin_attributes) { { admin: { email: 'xxx@gmail.com", password: "very-secret", password-confirmations: "very-secret" } } }
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Failure /Error: put '/admins', {admin: "abc@gmail.com", password: "very-secret", password-confirmation: "very-secret"}} ArgumentError: unknown keyword: admin.

Comment: am working on using let, so give me a minute. currently using what it says in the error message.

Comment: The params needs be passed as hash meaning inside `{}` which I forget about, I have edited my answer.

Comment: I tried put '/admins', params: {{admin: {email: "abc@gmail.com", password: "very-secret", password_confirmation: "very_secret"}}} I got a Syntax Error unexpected } expecting =>

Comment: The first `{` and last `}` used when using [`let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let), and since you are not using let you don't need the outer `{}`

Comment: If I take out the first and last {} I get an ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/admins"

Comment: I posted the answer in the comment above. You can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @flobacca, hope I helped more. You should be the one who answer this question, and mark it as correct ;)